# Converting polygon to points

Tags: polygon, borders, polygon-to-point

I am using QGIS.

I have a dataset of shapefile for admin0, admin1, admin2 and admin3 for the country of Syria.

I want to convert the polygon (the border of the subdistricts) to points (with lang and lat), in the end, Each polygon is a set of points that start and end at the same point, as I know.

Is there any way to do this?

For me, the most important is to have the lat and the lon for each point of each polygon.

Here is a link for the dataset from humandata.org:

syr_admin_shp_utf8_20230124.zipSHP (3.9M)
Updated: 5 February 2023

https://data.humdata.org/dataset/cod-ab-syr?

As well, from the same source, there is a GeoJSON file, that seems to contain the required dataset that I want, but I'm confused about how I can use it and change it to be readable.

syr_adm_unocha.zipGeoJSON (2.7M)
Updated: 20 February 2023

Answer (score 2):

1. [Densify by interval](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdensifygeometriesgivenaninterval) if you want/need to insert additional points where the polygon borders are long straight lines.
2. [Reproject layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisreprojectlayer) to EPSG:4326, if your layer isnt already in that coordinate system.
3. [Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisextractvertices) to create a point at each line vertice
4. [Add geometry attributes](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisexportaddgeometrycolumns) to add x and y coordinates to each point

[image]